# How to calculate a Fredholm index numerically

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

How can one calculate the index of a Fredholm operator numerically ?

In numerically calculations one uses always finte dimensional spaces.
But linear operators on finite dimensional spaces have always index zero.

Comment: If you happen to be lucky enough for the operator to be an (ordinary) differential operator, e.g. $Ly = y' - A(x)y$, and you are even more lucky so that the limits $A(\pm \infty)$ exist and have spectrum away from the imaginary axis, then the Fredholm index of L is the difference between the Morse index of A(\infty) and the Morse index of A(-\infty).


Comment: Are you thinking of operators on particular (function) spaces, or a Fredholm operator in full generality?

Comment: A linear operator between two DISTINCT finite-dimensional vector spaces does not have index zero, and that may help.

Comment: @Aaron: of course, assuming $A(x)$ is a path of operators on a *finite* dimensional space.

Comment: Alain ... but it has non-zero index for a TRIVIAL reason!

Comment: For Dirac operators one has the McKean-Singer formula which calculates the index in terms of heat kernel asymptotics.  That sounds to me like the sort of thing numerical analysts can deal with.

Comment: Bellissard was able to identify the quantum hall conductance with an index of a fredholm operator.
He worked directly on an infinite system (the whole plane).

Infinite systems can be approximated by finite systems.
So somehow it should be possible to approximate the index on finite systems.

For references see Jingbo Xia, Geometric Invariants of the Quantum Hall Effect, Commun. Math. Phys. 119, 29-50 (1988)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two key properties of the Fredholm index are

- It is a (norm)-continuous function from the bounded linear operators to the integers. In particular, if $A$ is a Fredholm operator, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for $\|A - B\| < \delta$, we have $index(A) = index(B)$. This tells you that you can approximate your problem.
- The Fredholm index doesn't see compact perturbations. So if $A$ is Fredholm and $K$ is compact, then $index(A +K ) = index(A)$. This tells you that you cannot do naive computations like picking some finite orthonormal set $\psi_{j}$ with $j=1,\dots,N$ and hope that the $N \times N$ matrix
  $$
   A_{j,k} = \langle \psi_j, A \psi_k\rangle
  $$
  tells you anything about the Fredholm index of $A$.

So you will now need to do something smarter. This is possible in many particular cases, for example for Toeplitz operators. The first property allows one to reduce the computation of the index to the computation of the winding number of a polynomial. Or the Atiyah--Singer index theorems reduces computing the index to some topological information ...

So to get a more meaningful answer, you will need to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: For more refined invariance theorems one the Fredholm index check Hoermander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators.*

Comment: Which volume? There are 4 if I remember correctly...


Comment: It's Vol III, Chapter 19 (*Elliptic Operators on a Compact Manifold Without Boundary*), Sec.19.1 *Abstract Fredholm Theory*.